# PHP ZF2 Installation - ZendSkeletonApplication is throwing Fatal Error RuntimeException

Tags: php, windows, apache, zend-framework2, installation

I'm trying to execute ZendSkeletonApplication example for frist time.
I've acted pursuant this articles from official Zend site:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

BUT

Why should I download again all dependecies (entire ZF2) via composer if I already downloaded it (ZF2) from Git as zip archive?

Or Does part with php composer doing anything else than downloading entire ZF2? (I've very slow connection so it's problem)

I still get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define
a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'

My approach is following: (Using Win7, PHP 5.3.5)

1. I downloaded entire ZF2 and ZendSkeletonApplication from Git as zip archives.
2. I Unziped ZF2 to htdocs/ directory. (Now my path to the framework is: xampp/htdocs/ZendFramework-2.3.1/ )
3. I Unziped ZendSkeletonApplication to htdocs/ (Path location: xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/ )
4. I checked presence of openssl extension. It's now enabled in php.ini
5. I added the Zend Framework’s library path to the PHP include_path in php.ini

   ( include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR; C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFramework-2.3.1\library" )
6. Now, If I type: localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/ , I get FatalError as I mentioned above..

Need I setup some other settings in ZendSkeletonApplication?
Is it possible to install dependencies via php composer from downloaded zip archive of ZF2? (No internet connection) ... If so, How can I setup the composer?

**EDIT:**

After XAMPP update (php 5.5) I was capable to successfuly access ZFSkeletonAppllication's introductory site (localhost/) after I set ZF2_PATH environment variable.

Ok, but unfortunately same FatalError still occur right when I got to the next chapter of ZF2 SkeletonApplication:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html

There, PHPUnit framework has been involved to ZF2 application. 
When I want to run phpunit I get same error as above:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
'Unable to load ZF2. ....

I setuped ZF2_PATH environment variable in httpd.conf to:

SetEnv ZF2_PATH c:/xampp/htdocs/ZendFramework-2.3.1/library

I really don't know what I can do now...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are include_path not working. You need to debug it why. Otherwise you can set `ZF2_PATH environment variable` as error itself demanded. It is easy way as you may setup framework at one folder while just need to setup ZF2_PATH variable. For debug, how ZF2 autoloading works, check /init_autloader.php .

No need to using composer every time for project setup. I also found it very annoying in composer way to install every time ZF2.

Comment: Yeah, after I added ZF2_PATH enviroment varialbe it's working now, thanks. But note that I had to reinstall PHP from 5.3.5 to 5.5 so that I made ZF2_PATH enviroment variable work. Otherwise I got error "Can't inherit abstract function Zend\Validator\Translator\TranslatorInterface::translate()" becouse of two implementations. However on the officiall ZF site they say that it requires php 5.3 and above... wierd and very stressful... This is only way it's working now.

Comment: Also after xampp reinstallation to newest version (php 5.5) in php.ini include_path still does not work... Do you have any suggestions yet, please? I want make it work...

Comment: I do not have experience on xampp (only on LAMP). Either i setup ZF2_PATH or copy/symlink ZF2 at vendor/ZF2/library/ . So It is always work through.